# Can such a pair of functions exist?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functions

Let $p\colon \mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $q\colon \mathbb{Z}^n\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that:

1. $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z^n}\colon q(x, p(y)) \leq q(x, p(z)) \iff d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)$
2. $\forall x\in \mathbb{Z^n}\colon q(x,\cdot)$ is monotone,

where $d$ denotes the Euclidean distance.

Can such $p$ and $q$ exist?

It's clear that $p$ cannot be something as simple as $\|x\|_2$, since for example in case of $n=2$ both $\|(1,0)\|_2 = \|(-1, 0)\| = 1$, but if $x = (2,0)$ then $(-1,0)$ is twice as far from it as $(1,0)$.

This makes me think, that $p$ somehow must encode the position in an invertible way.

An idea I had is that for a fixed $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ we could define $p$ using the following:
[image]

Since all the points are grid points, we could cover them with a countable number of circles (spheres). The sequence of radii is the square root of the integers that are expressable as the sum of $n$ squares. For $n\geq 4$, all the natural numbers form the sequence of radii, due to Lagrange's four-square theorem. The complicated part is the number of lattice points on these spheres, this is related to the [sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function).

But it's easy to see, that from the perspective of an $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ if we order the points first by the index of the sphere and then by the index on the sphere (which for $n>2$ can be also tricky) then the $$C_{1,1}, C_{1,2}, C_{1,3}, C_{1,4}, C_{2,1}, C_{2,2}, C_{2,3}, C_{2,4}, C_{3,1}, C_{3,2} \dots$$

sequence can define $p(y)$ as we need. For every point $y$ assign its index in this "C-sequence" as $p(y)$. So for example $p(C_{1,1}) = p((0,1)) = 1$, $p(C_{2,2}) = p((-1,-1)) = 6$, etc.

The problem is that this whole construct is for a fixed $x$ as we use it as the center of the spheres.

Let for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^n: c_x(y)$ denote the index of $y$ in this "C-sequence" if the center is $x$ (instead of $\underline{0}$ as in the example). It's easy to see that these $c_x$ functions are invertible.

Let's define $p$ as $p(x) = c_{\underline{0}}(x)$. Since they are invertible, we can define $q$ as a function that transforms the "C-sequence" from the perspective of $\underline{0}$ to the perspective of $x$:
$$q(x, p_y) = c_x(c_{\underline{0}}^{-1}(p_y))$$

Due to this strongly hacky definition it's true that if $p_y = p(y)$, $p_z = p(z)$ and $q(x,p_y) \leq q(x,p_z)$ then $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)$ since $q(x,p_y) = c_x(c_{\underline{0}}^{-1}(p_y)) = c_x(y)$ is the order of $y$ in the "C-sequence" from the perspective of $x$, which is equivalent to the distance of $y$ from $x$. So this satisfies my first condition.

There is only one problem left, $q(x,\cdot)$ is clearly not monotone. It's easy to craft a counter-example for $n=2$. Since $q(x,\cdot)$ is essentially the transformation taking $c_0$ into $c_x$, it's enough the find points $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $c_{\underline{0}}(a)\leq c_{\underline{0}}(b)\leq c_{\underline{0}}(c)$ but neither $c_x(a) \leq c_x(b) \leq c_x(c)$ nor $c_x(a) \geq c_x(b) \geq c_x(c)$ holds.

The following is a counter-example:
$$c_{(0,0)}((0,1)) = 1 \leq c_{(0,0)}((1,0)) = 2 \leq c_{(0,0)}((1,2)) = 13$$
but
$$c_{(2,1)}((0,1)) = 12 \geq c_{(2,1)}((1,0)) = 3 \leq c_{(2,1)}((1,2)) = 8$$

This was a kind of "intuitive" way of defining $p$ and $q$ but it didn't work out, so I'm wondering if it's really possible. It actually feels a little unnatural to have such functions, so maybe I should focus on proving their non-existence.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I added what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it cannot exist.

**Lemma 1:** Under property 1, the $p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ function is injective.

Proof: Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $p(x)=p(y)$. We want to show $x=y$.  Since $p(x)=p(y)$ we have:
$$q(y,p(x))=q(y,p(y))$$
In particular we have $q(y,p(x))\leq q(y,p(y))$ and so property 1 implies
$$d(y,x)\leq d(y,y)=0$$
and so $d(y,x)=0$, meaning $x=y$.
$\Box$

An injective function $p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ must take an infinite number of possible values. That is, $p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an infinite set. The next lemma contradicts Lemma 1, which means no such $p,q$ exist.

**Lemma 2:** Under both properties 1 and 2, the $p(\cdot)$ function can take at most two values.

Proof: Suppose there exist $y,z,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$p(y)<p(z)<p(w)$$
We reach a contradiction. We know $q(z,t)$ is monotonic in $t$, but we do not know if it is nondecreasing or nonincreasing.

- Case 1: Suppose $q(z,t)$ is nondecreasing in $t$. Since $p(y)<p(z)$ we have
  $$ q(z,p(y))\leq q(z,p(z))$$
  By property 1 this implies
  $$ d(z,y)\leq d(z,z)=0$$
  and so $z=y$, contradicting the fact $p(y)<p(z)$. So Case 1 is impossible.
- Case 2: Suppose $q(z,t)$ is nonincreasing in $t$. Since $p(z)<p(w)$ we have
  $$ q(z,p(z)) \geq q(z,p(w))$$
  which by property 1 implies
  $$\underbrace{d(z,z)}_{0} \geq d(z,w)$$
  and so $z=w$, contradicting $p(z)<p(w)$.
  $\Box$

Comment: Very nice proof, thank you, accepted your answer!

Do you think relaxing property 2. from monotony to convexity would change the outcome?